# how to get User IP address in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web, ip-address

This is the label

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblIp" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Here Code I used to get user IP address

```
 string VisitorsIPAddr = string.Empty;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
            {

                VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
                lblIp.Text = VisitorsIPAddr;
            }
            else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
            {
                VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
                lblIp.Text = VisitorsIPAddr;
            }
```

but Always I got the same result. That was **127.0.0.1** and always it goes to **else if** state.

further

`HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` **did not give any result. It always give nothing**

Comment: It seems you running this application at local end.

Comment: I am a student and I have no good knowledge on programming. Could you please explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the application at your own machine therefor you are the one sliding there, so you will always get `127.0.0.1` in the `else if`.
If you want to see another IP open the app and relevant port and get there with another machine.

Also the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is not always there (usually from normal web requests it will be but there are exceptions).

I think thats what Kundan Singh Chouhan tried to suggest, hope I am not wrong.